# How to get Image sent by user in facebook messenger through api.ai?

Tags: node.js, facebook-messenger, dialogflow-es

Anyone know how to retrieve an image sent by user, via api.ai? Do I just access the original body request? How do I do that when it does not seem to be sending to  api.ai? Do I just use my server to respond?

Answer (score 0):

API.AI includes information on the original request made to API.AI from the 1-click integrations in the `originalRequest` JSON attribute sent with every API.AI webhook request.  The format for a Facebook Messenger Rich Messaging message sent with an images has the form:

```
{
  "originalRequest": {
    "source": "facebook",
    "data": {
      "sender": {
        "id": "<PSID>"
      },
      "recipient": {
        "id": "<PAGE_ID>"
      },
      "timestamp": 1458692752478,
      "message": {
        "mid": "mid.145869661...",
        "attachments": [
          {
            "type": "image",
            "payload": {
              "url": "<IMAGE_URL>"
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Gist of full code example here](https://gist.github.com/matthewayne/438ea9b920e19bf40df956820d81d07e)

You can use the `originalRequest.data.message.attachments[0].payload.url` attribute to get the URL of the image.